# Ant - Where in the script did the error occur?

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

Since the output from ant does not tell me where an error is, is there a way, in the middle of an ant script, to check if an 'error' flag has been set?

I am running ant under IntelliJ if that matters.

Comment: Ant does tell you exactly where the error occurs, and even provides a full stack trace through your entire script. It's intellij that isn't giving you the information. Try running Ant directly through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the loglevel might be helpful.
See [Ant Build Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ant-build-tool-window.html)
click the button to set the [build file properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/build-file-properties.html)
and use `-debug` in the Ant command line field to set debugmode.